# How to disable Personal Contact Form display in User Registration

Tags: drupal-8

I am new to Drupal 8. 
I am setting up a simple site and do not want to allow users to contact each other. However, I do want to use forms such as Register for an event.

I have updated the user registration form by adding additional fields, such as first name, address, phone, etc.

/user/register displays the **Contact Settings** box:

"Allow other users to contact you via a personal contact form which keeps your email address hidden. Note that some privileged users such as site administrators are still able to contact you even if you choose to disable this feature."

with **Personal contact form** check box unchecked.

How can hide the display of the Contact settings box completely?

Answer (score 3):

That form is added by the contact module. You can either

1. Disable that module on /admin/modules
2. Disable the contact output on /admin/config/people/accounts/form-display
3. Create some overrides (so you can disable it for specific roles or other logic)

### Overrides

If you want to override the 
default behaviour, you need to create a new module and implement a [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function yourmodulename_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'user_form' || $form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    // Do some checks (e.g. role, permission), and then:
    unset($form['contact']);
  }
}
```

The contact module adds the form via form_alter hook as well, so it could very well be that the order of hook execution messes things up (this was the case for me). You might have to implement [hook_module_implements_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.2.x) as well, as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function yourmodulename_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook)
{
  if($hook == 'form_alter') {
    $group = $implementations['yourmodulename'];
    unset($implementations['yourmodulename']);
    $implementations['yourmodulename'] = $group;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to precise, modules can't be "unchecked" from D8, you'll have to disabled it first  (http://my-site.com/admin/modules/uninstall)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach for me to disabling the personal contact form was:

1. Following the instructions to set personal contact form off by default (from [Drupal contact module documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/contact/overview))

   - Navigate to the Account Settings page (Administration > Configuration > People > Accounts or http://example.com/admin/config/people/accounts)
   - In the Contact settings section specify whether the contact form is enabled for users by default.
   - Click "Save configuration."
2. Go to /admin/config/people/accounts/form-display (as instructed by Marcus above)
3. Move "Contact settings" to disabled.
4. Click save

So now the personal contact form is off by default for all **future** users and they don't have the ability to turn it on. Note that this does not change things for existing users on the site.

Comment: That's not the best method to achieve this, but this have the advantage to not require development at all.